# Accessing the variable of parent class shows subclass variable

Tags: java, inheritance, super

I encountered an example which is not at all clear to me.
In this example result is :
feline cougar c c

But we call in method super.type.

```
class Feline {
   public String type = "f ";
   public Feline() {
   System.out.print("feline ");
   }
 }
 public class Cougar extends Feline {
   public Cougar() {
     System.out.print("cougar ");
      }
      void go() {
       type = "c ";
        System.out.print(this.type + super.type);
     }
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Cougar().go();
         }
        }
```

I expected feline cougar c f.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one variable. However you access that variable, it will give the same value.